# Bridge crossing over - java multithreading problem

Tags: java, multithreading

A bridge with one traffic lane connects two cities. Cars from both towns use that bridge in order to travel from one city to another. A bridge can be blocked if cars from both directions are on the bridge at the same time. In order to solve this problem, people placed two semaphores (with green and red lights) at the both sides of the bridge (when on one semaphore is green light on the other one is red light). The lights change their value after some time has passed (the specific value is not given). After a car crosses the bridge it stays in that city for a while and than comes back and so on... Write a program that describes given situation and forbids deadlock.

This is from console:

```
The green light is on on the right.
Lights are changing.
Car 4 wait on the semaphore.
```

I think this is the problem and with the left light also. Why lights don't change more often, is there a way to fix that? Additionaly, Car 4 is problematic it, why does it wait on the semaphore? This is my first question on this site, sorry if it is not put together quite well. I would appreciate if someone could let me know if this is a good approach. Thankful in advance.

When I run the program

```
public class Car extends Thread{

    int id;
    int direction;
    Bridge b;
    
    public Car(int id, int dir, Bridge b) {
        this.id = id;
        this.direction = dir;
        this.b = b;
    }
    
    public void crossOver() {
        int city1 = 1, city2 = 2;
        if (this.direction == 2) {
            city1 = 2;
            city2 = 1;
        } 
        try {
            System.out.println("Car "+((Car)Thread.currentThread()).id+" is crossing over the bridge"
                    + " from city "+city1+" in city "+city2+"."
                    );
            sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
            try {
                sleep(1);
            } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            b.waitB(this.direction);
            crossOver();
            int city = 1;
            if(this.direction == 1)
                city = 2;
            System.out.println("Car "+this.id+" is in the city "+ city);
            try {
                sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            }
            if (this.direction == 1) this.direction++;
            else this.direction--;
       }
    }
}
```

```
public class Bridge extends Thread{

Semaphore s1, s2;
    
    public Bridge(Semaphore s1,Semaphore s2) {
        this.s1 = s1;
        this.s2 = s2;
    }
    
    public synchronized void turnOnSemaphoreLeft() {
        s1.color = 1;
        s2.color = 0;
        System.out.println("The green light is on on the left.");
        notifyAll();
         
    }
    public synchronized void turnOnSemaphoreRight() {
        s2.color = 1;
        s1.color = 0;
        System.out.println("The green light is on on the right.");
        notifyAll();
    }
    
    public void run() {
        while(true) {
              turnOnSemaphoreLeft();
              System.out.println("Lights are changing.");
              try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
              
           
              turnOnSemaphoreRight();
              System.out.println("Lights are changing.");
              try {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    
    public synchronized void waitB(int direction) {
        if (direction == 1) {
            if (s1.color == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Car "+((Car)Thread.currentThread()).id+" wait on the semaphore.");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } 
            }
        }
        else if (direction == 2) {
            if (s2.color == 0) {
                try {
                    System.out.println("Car "+((Car)Thread.currentThread()).id+" wait on the semaphore.");
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
}
```

```
public class Semaphore () {

    int color; //if color = 1 than is green light, if color = 0 than is red light 
}
```

```
public class Main() {
     public static void main(String[] args) {
        Semaphore s1 = new Semaphore();
        Semaphore s2 = new Semaphore();
        
        Bridge m = new Bridge(s1,s2);
        
        Car a1 = new Car(1, 1, m);
        Car a2 = new Car(2, 2, m);
        Car a3 = new Car(3, 2, m);
        Car a4 = new Car(4, 1, m);
        Car a5 = new Car(4, 2, m);
        Car a6 = new Car(4, 1, m);
        Car a7 = new Car(4, 2, m);
        
        m.start();
        
        a1.start();
        a2.start();
        a3.start();
        a4.start();
        a5.start();
        a6.start();
        a7.start();


     }
}
```